# Typescript inferred incorrectly when declaring type with optional key

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript and basically scratching my head on dealing with this simple problem.

I have object array declared like this:

```
[
    {
        name: 'XSmall',
        style: css`
            height: 32px;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding: 0 16px;
        `
    },
    {
        name: 'Small',
        style: css`
            height: 40px;
            font-size: 16px;
            padding: 0 16px;
        `
    }
]
```

Then declaring types like this

```
interface StyleProperty  {
    name?: string
    style?:
    | FlattenInterpolation<ThemeProps<DefaultTheme>>
    | FlattenInterpolation<ThemedCssFunction<DefaultTheme>>
} 

type Style<T> = T | {
  [key: string] :  string | StyleProperty
}
```

Then use in the following code below:

```
const SIZE = sizes.reduce((size : Style<StyleProperty>, currentSize : Style<StyleProperty>) => {
    size[currentSize.name] = currentSize.name
    return size;
}, {})
```

but it does not work since `currentSize.name` inferred as `StyleProperty` even though it should be a string.

How do I sort this out. I'm new to typescript and hopefully someone may help explain.

Thank you.

Comment: `currentSize.name` *could* be a string but could also be a `StyleProperty` and if it is a `StyleProperty` `size[currentSize.name]` would error. You will need to check if `currentSize` is indeed a `StyleProperty` and does have the optional `name` property manually.

Comment: may I know how should I do it?

Comment: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html

Comment: Please consider editing the above code to constitute a [mcve] as described in [ask].  Ideally someone could drop the code into any IDE and demonstrate the issue. I can see that you are treating a `StyleProperty | string | undefined` as if it were a `string`, but it's not clear what you want to do in the case where it is `StyleProperty | undefined`. Maybe the problem is that `styles` should be `StyleProperty[]`, but you haven't actually defined `styles` or the `css` template literal tag function. So I'm not sure how best to advise, other than the generic "be careful with how you type things".